# Get jQuery to set width as percentage rather than pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an example set up [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darbybrown/8JnGw/3/), the jQuery currently sets the width as a fixed pixel width. So when the browser width is decreased the bars go off the screen to the right.
My question is how do i get jQuery to set the width to a percentage instead?

```
<div class="bars">
    <div class="meter">
        <span style="width: 88%"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="meter">
        <span style="width: 62%"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".meter > span").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 3600);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first calculate the relative percentage between this two widths, like so:

```
var relativePercentage = ($(this).width()/$(this).parent('div').width())*100;
```

Then you can set this as the target width, remembering to add the `%` number (or it will get the value in `px`), like so:

```
$(this)
    .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
    .width(0)
    .animate({
        width: relativePercentage + '%'
    }, 3600);
```

**[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/emekiv/1)**

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".meter > span").each(function() {
   $(this).data("origWidth", ($(this).width() / $(this).parent().width()) * 100)
          .width(0)
          .animate({ width: $(this).data("origWidth") + "%" }, 3600);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8JnGw/4/)

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8JnGw/5/)**</kbd>

```
$(".meter > span").each(function() {
    $(this).animate({ width: $(this).data("width")+"%" }, 3600);
});
```

this HTML:

```
<span data-width="88"></span>
```

and in the CSS set width to `0%`;

Resizing the window your `SPAN`s will keep the `%` width.